# Bootstrap 3 | Responsive col width and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a Bootstrap page for the first time. Used to working in HTML/CSS and all just not bootstrap. I'm having some difficulty with the following:

I created a fluid ( full width ) container that spans 4 columns.
The 1st column contains an image, the 2nd text, the 3rd an image and the 4th text again. The next row of columns is alternating. 
I want my columns to have a responsive width and height so that if i adjust the viewport, the colums are always squared and stretching the full page. I just can't seem to get this to work. Tried various things. Setting max width, using percentages, background images, img scr tags that scale to 100% etc. but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone tell me how i can make this happen? 
Greatly appreciated. No problem if JS or JQuery is needed to make it work. I got the basics covered so i know how to do that if someone points me in the right direction ( not a JS wizard to figure this one out on my own just yet ).

For example, i provided my HTML markup.
The CSS is pretty basic. Just provided the background images in the ft-img columns and some styling for the fonts. Also, currently all col have a fixed height of 400 pixels but that is abviously not the way to go. :P

```
<div class="container-fluid main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-img ft-1">  
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-text">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Paragraph </p>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-img ft-2">  
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-text">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Paragraph </p>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-text">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Paragraph </p>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-img ft-1">  
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-text">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Paragraph </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 ft-img ft-2">  
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

As asked, here's the CSS. I initially did not provide it since it's just the basics and it's just one of the things i tried. As said above.

```
.ft-img {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 400px;
}
.ft-text {
    background: url('../img/bg.png');
    background-position: 10% 10%;
    height: 400px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 40px;
}
.ft-text h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ft-text p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ft-1 {
    background: url('../img/ft/ft-1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.ft-2 {
    background: url('../img/ft/ft-2.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your css/ maybe set up a fiddle to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be fluid, you can't specify fixed units (px).

Consider using the `vw` unit to make your heights relative to their widths to maintain squares.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths